# checking if there is an existing Sidekiq job for a given object ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq worker that takes an object instance ID and it uses the "default" queue:

```
  class ExampleWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(id)
      instance = Record.find_by(id: id)
      (...)
```

How can I check If there is an exisiting Job for a given instance.id before calling this worker with `ExampleWorker.perform_async(inst.id)`

it's probably worth mentioning that it's the Sidekiq Pro version being used.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to Enterprise, then you'll get [unique jobs](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Unique-Jobs)

Comment: If not possible to upgrade, then this is a difficult problem to solve as stated and you should try to sidestep it. Rather than trying to not queue a job if one exists, queue it anyway. But when performing the job, check some conditions again to see if the job already ran and if so, do nothing.